# HBase - How does the Scan.setBatch effect ResultScanner's Next Number of Iterations?

Tags: hbase

Let's say I have:

- A Table with one column family CF.
- CF has 10 Columns [C1,..,C10]
- Table has 2 rows ['r1','r2'].  Each row is completely populated (each row has 10 cell values).

Now I create a `Scan` that would return all the cells values for the two rows from the table.

But I set the batch to `scan.setBatch(5)`. I query the table successfully using the scan and get back `ResultScanner`.

Now when I do `resultScanner.next()` I'll get a result back.

I'm guessing that I have to call `next` 4 times to iterate through all the cells.  Is that right?

Iterations:

1. returns 'r1', values for 'C1' to 'C5'
2. returns 'r1', values for 'C6' to 'C10'
3. returns 'r2', values for 'C1' to 'C5'
4. returns 'r2', values for 'C6' to 'C10'

Is that correct?

I already know where the api doc is published...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes thats correct. Mostly used with large number of columns. I hope you know setCache, is at row level. Also a large number of columns is not a recommended design pattern. Happy learning